# How can I create something like this in css?

Tags: html, css, border

I want to create a partial border around these different font headings. How can i create these, please help. I have tried everything but nothing is working. Sorry, noob here

Comment: Did you forget to add links / images?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TczXu.png

Comment: Sorry, added the screenshot again

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `border-top: 10px` but you can use pseudo elements like that:

```css
div{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
  border-right: 5px solid grey;

}

div:before{
  content: '';
  width: 70px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

To be more specific, add `:after` or `:before` on your `div` and add what I added on my example and you can change the height/width/color and make sure to add `position:absolute` and add some specific properties like top, left..., to position that line where you want.